# How to center Masonry Items?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I have set up masonry to display items as such:

```
$('#list').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.propitem',
  columnWidth: 230
});
```

This works, but all items (`.propitem`) float to the left. For example if my container `#list` is 600px wide there will be two columns to the left but a gap to the right of them where the remaining 140px is. I would like to center the 2 columns with a 70px 'margin' on either side.

I have tried using css to centre these, but had no luck, eg:

```
#list {
text-align: center;
}
```

Would anyone know the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: you cannot center floated items.

Comment: add padding instead margin, or reduce width of container (padding:0 70px; ?)

Answer (score 21):

You need to use `fitWidth` (or, in older versions, `isFitWidth`) along with CSS to make it work. Here's the reference: http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#isfitwidth

```
$('#list').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.propitem',
  columnWidth: 230,
  fitWidth: true
});
```

and

```
#list {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: O well, it certainly *used* to. :-(

Comment: Works well with version 4.1.x